randomize output gain with soapy block
I found on git code for randomize output using gr-osmo block and code is working fine, you need to enter min value for gain, like this
self.osmosdr_sink_0.set_if_gain(35, 0)
and after in script this
self.osmosdr_sink_0.set_if_gain(random.randint(0,47), 0)
I can't get it to work with soapy block, syntax is little bit different, and I don't know python at all
self.soapy_hackrf_sink_0.set_gain(0, 'VGA', min(max(35, 0.0), 0.0))
I don't know syntax for soapy block after, need to include this, but after I don't know
self.osmosdr_sink_0.set_if_gain(random.randint....
I'm usually getting this error  self.soapy_hackrf_sink_0.set_gain(random.randint(0, 47), 0) ValueError: sink: Channel 41 is not activated. 
I try already valuee like min and max, but it's not working also
self.osmosdr_sink_0.set_if_gain(random.randint(35,47), 0)
